# DefinitelyTyped file for headjs. Where to find?

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped, headjs

Where can I find DefinitelyTyped file for head.js utility?

I have searched on various forums but failed to find one.

Answer (score 4):

> Where can I find DefinitelyTyped file for head.js utility?

It doesn't exist : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped DT is just a community created list of type informations. Since it doesn't exist I started a request for it so that people (perhaps even you) can work on it if they want : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/issues/4318